# Как удалить error записи из ответа

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Собираю список друзей участников сообщества ВК следующим образом:

```
for x in hall_of_fame['user_id']:
  url = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?', params={
      'access_token': token,
      'v': 5.131,
      'offset': 0,
      'user_id': x,
      'fields': 'user_id',
      'access_token': token
  })
  data = url.json()
```

Получаю вот такой ответ:
[image: Ответ на запрос получения списка друзей]

Подскажите, как удалить все строки 'error' и превратить это в dataframe, потому что
`data = url.json().['response']` - выходит ошибка `KeyError: 'response'`

Comment: Данные должны быть не изображением.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь работать с JSON как со словарём питона, но это так не работает.

Comment: Добавить проверку вида `if data.get("error") is not None:` и не сохранять ответы с ошибками

Comment: @mironovmeow, а почему не просто `if "error" in data`?

Comment: @entrance, соглашусь, можно и так, разницы никакой не будет